# How to ask Ubuntu/Gnome to reboot?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I sometimes need to reboot to in another GRUB entry. It is easy to tell grub to temporarily change the default entry for the next reboot, but then you have to tell the system to reboot. I'd like to make these into a single action. I know it could easily be a script :

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
grub-reboot 3
shutdown -r now
```

But I'd like to go the Gnome way, and be asked  if I wan't to reboot or shutdown, validating with me that I'm ready and make sure I don:'t have other session opened. To do this I need to know what is happening when I click Shutdown/Close session in the systray so I can call it from some other place.

Even better, add an entry in the system menu ("Reboot in > new entry...") and would popup a dialog where you could type the name/number of the next grub entry to use.

Writing this, I read about Gnome extensions. I guess it's the way to go ? Any suggestion on where to start ?

Comment: I think a simple shell script could be added as the `Exec` param of a `my-reboot.desktop` file (one that goes into `~/.local/share/applications/`), and then it(s icon) could be added to the dock by putting it into the `org.gnome.shell favorite-apps` gsettings variable, e.g. with the `dconf-editor` app. Shell scripts can have an interactive menu feature, that at its most basic, can be interacted with in `gnome-terminal`. But you can call the `zenity` software /  command, to make the script use real graphical dialog popups when executed.

Comment: Here is an introductory article on zenity: https://www.howtogeek.com/107537/how-to-make-simple-graphical-shell-scripts-with-zenity-on-linux/ and here is the zenity documentation: https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/zenity.1.html I was thinking about maybe the "radiolist" widget. This article shows the radio buttons just before the closing "Conclusion" section: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-graphical-widgets-in-bash-scripts-with-zenity Update: I found the official "zenity manual": https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/